# Why is this duckmap blocking?

Tags: raku

I'm trying to list all files in a directory with this function:

```
sub list-directory($dir = '.') {
    my @todo = $dir.IO.dir;
    @todo = @todo.duckmap( -> $_ where $_.d { @todo.push($_.IO.dir); } );
    @todo = @todo.duckmap( -> $_ where IO {.Str} );
    return @todo;
}
```

The first duckmap is to list all subdirectories and the second one (this doesn't finish) is to convert the IO objects to Str.

Anyone knows why the second one isn't stopping?

Comment: The IO check in the second duckmap is to avoid arrays added by the previous one.

Comment: Oh I think the error is in @todo.push being added to the map, I should have typed $_.dir

Comment: Yes I think you are modifying `@todo` as you are traversing it with `duckmap`. Probably causing an infinite loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Hakon has said, it was a infinite loop. Here is the code fixed:

```
sub list-directory($dir = '.') {
    my @todo = $dir.IO.dir;
    @todo = @todo.duckmap( -> $_ where $_.d { @todo.push($_.IO.dir); $_; } );
    grep { !.IO.d }, @todo.List.flat;
    @todo.map({.Str});
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this code works as you intend? It still looks like dodgy code to me (even if it works when you've tried it). First, `@todo.duckmap...` means you're walking `@todo` but if the `@todo.push...` code executes it'll modify it. Second, your `grep { !.IO.d }, @todo.List.flat;` line looks like it won't do anything.

Comment: I know this is an awful code. I did a it recursively but someone told me that it could be done with duckmap (this is the only way I can think of using it).

The grep line is actually doing something because it tests if the element is a directory and in that case it deletes it.

And yep, I'm adding elements to the array while I'm walking it, but it is no problem because it always finishs.